# Nominal Variables in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

How do i specify `NominalVariables` in `NonlinearModelFit` there doesn't seem to be a parameter for this like in the case of `LinearModelFit` and `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.

Comment: You'll need to create your own dummy variables.  (And doing so is usually faster than using `NominalVariables` in both `LinearModelFit` and `GeneralizedLinearModelFit`.)  Do you have a small data set and proposed model you could add to your question?  That would get you more specific help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create your own dummy variables and the best way doing that depends on your data and the types of models being fit.  Here's just one way:

```
(* "Enhanced" data from LinearModelFit example *)
data = {{a, 0, 1}, {b, 2, 2}, {a, 2, 1.8}, {b, 0, 2.5}, {a, 4, 1.74}, {b, 2, 2.5}};

(* Get unique list of values of the nominal variable *)
nominalVariables = DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 1]]]

(* Now use DiscreteIndicator in NonlinearModelFit *)
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, c0 + c1 Exp[y] + 
   DiscreteIndicator[x, a, nominalVariables] (y + 1)^c2,
  {c0, c1, c2}, {x, y}]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {c0 -> 1.7160282337057398, c1 -> 0.0026619137327001875, c2 -> -3.233168500749501} *)
```